# How to exit a strategy in tradingview on either achieving a target or at a stoploss or a condition

Tags: pine-script

From what I understand, according to the pine script reference manual at https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/
the parameter when in the  function strategy.exit is used only for placing the order
this is what the documentation says
*"Condition of the order. The order is placed if condition is 'true'. If condition is 'false', nothing happens (the previously placed order with the same ID is not cancelled). Default value is 'true'."*

This implies that the order may not be necessarily executed when the condition is satisfied. For example, if I have a condition where I would exit a trade when RSI is less than 30, and if I have

```
strategy.exit("IdOfThisOrder","EntryOrderID", when=rsilessthan30, profit=100,loss=50)
```

(which means that I have a profit target of 100 picks and a stoploss of 50 ticks)
then, assuming that neither the profit target as been met not the stoploss only the order will be placed and it will not be executed.

If I have to exit the position when RSI<30, then I will actually have to test for that and then call strategy.close

```
if rsi<30
  strategy.close("EntryOrderID")
```

additionally, I will also have to cancel the existing order which means

```
if rsi<30
  strategy.cancel("IdOfThisOrder")
  strategy.close("EntryOrderID")
```

In effect, the target and profit will be taken care of by strategy.exit and any other condition by strategy.close

This appears to be kind of complicated and perhaps I'm not able to understand the usage. I sometimes get results which are not completely clear stop so I wanted to understand how these are being used together

I looked around for any examples but could not find any. Can someone please advise? Thank you for any answers

Answer to the first comment:
This code:

```
if (shortentercondition )
    strategy.entry("Tech1", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Exit","Tech1",profit=profittarget,stop=sl_level)

if ( shortclosecondition )
    strategy.cancel("Exit")
    strategy.close("Tech1")
```

and this code:
    if (shortentercondition )
        strategy.entry("Tech1", strategy.short)
        // strategy.exit("Exit","Tech1",profit=profittarget,stop=sl_level)

```
if ( shortclosecondition or proftconditionmet or slconditionmet)
    // strategy.cancel("Exit")
    strategy.close("Tech1")
```

should be equivalent in my case. But the first one gives me a  loss(approx -10%) and  the second one gives profit (approx 20%). I cannot figure out the reasons why the trades were exited in many cases in the first case. I can provide details of the actual trades but that would perhaps be a lot of data to troubleshoot over this forum. Hopefully you can find point out the differences in this code.

Comment: Could you please give an example of a result you get that isn't clear?

Comment: @Jaybird thank you for your response. I have added the code in the original question since there is limited space in the comments. Looking forward to your response. Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve this meanwhile? I am facing exactly the same issue.